# d-separation in Bayes Network vs separation in undirected graph

Tags: graphical-model, conditional-independence

I've been teaching myself about d-separation and am trying to answer the following question. Given the graphs below, write down all conditional independence relationships involving the random variable C i.e. $C \perp X|Y$

Note: I've had to use $\perp$ for conditional independence as I don't know how to write the proper symbol in LaTeX without adding stuff to preamble (which stackexchange doesn't have).

Here are the graphs:

[image]

For image (i), we have a tail-to-tail relationship at B which means C and A are d-separated and so I have $C \perp A|B$. I cannot find any more conditional independence relationships here of the form $C \perp X | Y$ since both $B$ and $D$ are adjacent to $C$ and therefore not valid. Is this right?

For image (ii), we have a head-to-tail relationship at B and D. I think this means $C \perp A|B$ and $C \perp A|D$ and $C \perp A| \{ B,D\}$. I was tempted to write $C \perp B|D$ but I don't think this is valid since only one of the possible paths from C to B would be d-separated. So I find a total of three valid conditional indpendence relationships. Is that right?

For image (iii) and (iv), the problem is now that the graphs are undirected and I have not been able to find as much material online to help with this. I was wondering if someone could help with the following:

(a) explain the meaning of the black squares in (iv)
(b) link to some notes/videos that might help with finding conditional independencies in undirected graphs

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(a) The black squares represent factors in a factor graph. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_graph) is the wiki page about factor graphs.

(b) [A pdf from stat cmu](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat700/UG.pdf) is a reference about Undirected Graph / Markov Random Field.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I found some helpful stuff as well. Understand it all now :)